Unable to access my EKS cluster when deploying using github actions
I'm completely stuck. I wrote terraform code to deploy an eks cluster with worker nodes and when i deploy it using terraform, everything works and I'am able to do kubectl get nodes, however, when I use push to github and use github actions, everything still deploys, but when I try to access the cluster using kubectl get nodes, I get this error:

E0505 22:34:58.473467   28812 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0505 22:34:59.011805   28812 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0505 22:34:59.764169   28812 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0505 22:35:00.350556   28812 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E0505 22:35:01.067397   28812 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

I should mentioned that in my github repo I made sure to add the IAM role arn of the GitHubActionsTerraformIAMrole which was part of the OIDC setup. I added it as an environment secret.
Here is my workflow file, Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!
name: Terraform Deployment Workflow
on:
push:
branches:
- main
- dev
permissions:
id-token: write
contents: read
jobs:
terraform:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
environment: ${{ (github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'production') || (github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' && 'staging') || 'dev' }}
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Configure AWS credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.7.0
  with:
    aws-region: us-east-1
    role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.IAM_ROLE }}
    audience: sts.amazonaws.com

- name: Terraform Initialize
  run: terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=project-x" -backend-config="key=terraform.tfstate" -backend-config="region=us-east-1"
  working-directory: ./roots/main-eks-root/

- name: Terraform Plan
  run: terraform plan -var-file="project.tfvars" -out=tfplan
  working-directory: ./roots/main-eks-root/

- name: Terraform Apply
  run: terraform apply -auto-approve "tfplan"
  working-directory: ./roots/main-eks-root/

I tried deploying both configuration using the same tfvars file locally and github actions. only local worked so im guessing its something with github actions credentials but I'm not sure.

This is probably related more to the kubernetes provider configuration than to the GHA configuration.

Are you adding the cluster that GHA is creating to your kubeconfig locally? Also, to clarify, you are saying that the cluster gets deployed correctly from GHA (i.e. you can see it in your cloud account) but you simply cannot interact with it from local, correct?
